# Laravel Encryptable Trait Failing Authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, encryption

I'm running into trouble with authentication handling in my Laravel 5.5. I have installed an `Encryptable` trait according to [this post here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/encrypting-model-data). I then used the authentication generator to establish the base routes, views and handler.

I can successfully register new accounts and visually see that all of the data is encrypted, but I cannot successfully authenticate through the login screen.

This seems to be failing during the `Auth::attempt($credentials)` call. My troubleshooting is pointing to the encryptable trait because when I comment that section out, the authentication works fine.

Can someone offer insight as to how to handle authentication using this method of model encryption?

I have attempted disabling encryption for the username field, but this didn't seem to help. The password field was never being encrypted, becasue it is being hashed by bcrypt.

1st Edit:
So, with an understanding of how traits work... The `Encryptable` trait seems to be overloading the getAttribute/setAttribute functions. This would mean that Eloquent's querying functions like `where`, `find`, etc. will just be "looking at" encrypted values.

2nd Edit:
The source code provided for the `Encryptable` trait was not returning proper values for unencrypted values. This was changed and authentication was restored. To those using the same code snippet, in the `get_attribute()` function, change the `else` block so that it `return $value;`.

I appreciate all insights,
Dan

Comment: How you are storing credentials value , share those code ?

Comment: @C2486 the username is the user's email, which gets encrypted going into the database. I need to find a means of overloading the querying functions of Eloquent to handle this encryptable trait.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish by encrypting user info? If you're encrypting the username, authentication would require the decryption of every single entry in your users table, which is highly inefficient and even unnecessary in my opinion. Be aware that Laravel encryption is not really *that* secure since the private key is stored in plain text in your app. Anyone who gains access to your app also gains access to your private key and therefore your encrypted data. If you want real security you're going to need a hardware security module (HSM), which are expensive.

Comment: This is what I thought. Thank you for your insight @Mike. What I was trying to do was provide a level of data protection for the values in the database. That way, the database by itself would be of no value to a thief. I agree that the key would be easily available, but it feels like it's better than plain-text. Other than HSM, what can I do to provide decent security for personal information my app will store?

Comment: I would still say that this form of encryption is very useful, whether or not you have an HSM.   It is pretty general knowledge that if you gain access to an application server, you'll be able to read decrypted data.  That's not usually the concern encryption is trying to prevent, the concern is protecting data at rest, like database dumps for example.

Answer (score 0):

This form of encryption will void your ability to search the table for the encrypted fields.  You won't be able to reproduce the same string because Laravel uses a random iv when producing encrypted data.  An IV, or initialization vector, serves a similar purpose as a salt in hashing, to randomize the stored data.

Due to this randomization of data, you wouldn't even be able to search your table by re-encrypting the search data:

```
User::where('email', Crypt::encrypt('email@email.com')); 
// won't find anything even if an encrypted value of email@email.com exists
```

Running in an interactive shell allows you to see encrypt returns a completely different value on subsequent runs:

```
>>> json_decode(base64_decode(Crypt::encrypt('email@email.com')))->value
=> "zpA0LBsbkGCAagxLYB6kiqwJZmm7HSCVm4QrUw6W8SE="
>>> json_decode(base64_decode(Crypt::encrypt('email@email.com')))->value
=> "VKz8CWVzR66cv/J7J09K+TIVwQPxcIg+SDqQ32Sr7rU="
```

Therefore, you may want to be selective about what you actually encrypt.  Encrypt things that are sensitive and you wouldn't use to lookup an entity.  This could be something like social security numbers, government IDs, credit card numbers, and bank account numbers.